# 2D plane's Distribution

Tags: probability, probability-theory

> A total of $n$ , $n>0$,nodes are placed on a 2D plane.To determine the links be these nodes ,sequential experiments of coin tosses are conducted as follows:
>
> For each pair of nodes , a coin is randomly chosen from a box of a sufficiently large number of coins and then tossed . 
>   If the **head appears**, a link is drawn to connect the two nodes .
>
> After the toss , the coin is returned to the box and the experiment repeats for the next pair.Note that due to production problems at the mint ,all coins in the box are biased.
>   The probability of head is different for different coins ,but it can be assumed to follow a $U[0.4,0.8]$

---

Question:

The set of nodes and the links thus drawn between them constitute a random graph . Let $X$ be the number of links in the graph.What is $f(x)$,$E[X]$,$V[X]$,$M_X(t)$?

An isolated node is formed if it is not connected to any other nodes in the graph Let $Y$ be the number of isolated nodes in the graph.What is $E[Y]$?

---

I don't know the question whether can use $Wald's equation$ to solve $E[X],V[X]$ 
Assume each node be connected success be 0 fail be 1 $Ber(Y)$ and 
and $E[E[X|Y]]=>(C^n_2*E[X]) $ will get $E[X]$ .Is right or not?
I don't know how to derive the pmf.

Comment: I think your approach is alright. Please go ahead.

Comment: but I don't know how to derive the PMF

Comment: So $\displaystyle X = \sum_{i=1}^{\binom {n} {2}} Z_i$ where $Z_i|U_i = u_i \sim \text{Bernoulli}(u_i)$, $U_i \sim \text{Uniform}(0.4, 0.8)$. If you do not observe those realized values $u_i$ and those $U_i$ are independent, then actually it should be just similar to a Binomial problem. If there is only one common $U$, then it can be as ugly as the Beta-Binomial distribution. If those $u_i$ are given, then it is not tractable.